# Laravel json response after user input use ajax to get data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5, instagram-api

Using instagram API with Laravel, i had a problem with page that lets the user input a **tagname** and search images for that tag.

When i fill input and hit `submit` i get a `json` response that is posted to second page.

The problem is that i want to get the response from second page to a third one for display images to the user.

When i go to the "test" page url directly without posting anything its empty thats why i get an empty `jsonArray` back to third page.

How can i get the data with Ajax AFTER the "test" page have got the Json response? i have used `.submit();` but it dosent work.

Here is my code:

**AJAX :**

```
 $(function() {
    $("#loader").hide();
    $("#theForm").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'test',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#loader").show();
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#loader').hide();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    $("#theData").append(
                        "<div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'>" +
                        "<div class='thumbnail'>" +
                        "<a target='_blank' href='" + value.link + "'> " +
                        "<img src='" + value.images.standard_resolution.url + "'></img>" + "</a>" +
                        "<p>Posted by: " + value.user.username + "</p>" +
                        "<p>Likes: " + value.likes.count + "</p>"
                        + "</div>"
                        + "</div>");
                });
            },error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: store the data into global variable and then post to third page

Comment: how can i store a laravel response()->json(); to global variable?

Comment: store the ajax response data into javascript global variable and then post to third page. In controler you can redirect to route with response